# How to do CRUD operations on Microsoft's Dataverse tables using Python?

Tags: python, dataverse

Can anyone point me another alternative to do CRUD operations on MS Dataverse using Python?

I have an Azure AD App registration but if you can provide steps on how to set it up to achieve my goal, that would be great. I'm a bit new with the MS platform, especially with Dataverse.

Apologies in advance if ever this has been answered already.

I was following a blog (link below) but it is unreachable at the moment.
Blog: https://andyhowes.co/easily-connect-to-dataverse-microsoft-dynamics-with-python/